# Solving ${{\bf{x}}^T}{\bf{Ax}} = {\bf{0}}$ for ${\bf{x}}$ when ${\bf{A}}$ is a symmetrical singular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a quadratic form ${{\bf{x}}^T}{\bf{Ax}} = {\bf{0}}$ where ${\bf{A}}$ is a symmetrical singular matrix, and I would like to solve for ${\bf{x}}$. I have a feeling that there are infinite solutions to this. Is there a formal way of expressing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A$ is symmetric, there is an orthonormal basis $\mathbf{v}_1, \dots, \mathbf{v}_n$ of eigenvectors of $A$; say $A \mathbf{v}_i = \lambda_i \mathbf{v}_i$ for each $1 \le i \le n$. Then for each $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ we have
$$\mathbf{x} = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \mathbf{v}_i$$
for some scalars $x_1,\dots,x_n$, which gives
$$\mathbf{x}^T A \mathbf{x} = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i x_i^2$$
Since $A$ is singular, $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$—without loss of generality that $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = \cdots = \lambda_r = 0$ (where $r \ge 1$). Then every vector $\mathbf{x} \in \langle \mathbf{v}_1, \dots, \mathbf{v}_r \rangle$ is a solution to $\mathbf{x}^TA\mathbf{x} = 0$. (There might be other solutions too.)